# PHP Date format m/d/Y returns tomorrow's date

Tags: php, date

Can someone please tell me why this statement returns tomorrow's date rather than today?

```
$date = date("m/d/Y");
echo $date;
```

Comment: Is your Servertime right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have set the timezone properly, so `date` could be producing a date in a timezone in which the date has already changed. You can use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to change the timezone `date` uses.

For a list of timezone strings to use with the above function, check the [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: hmmm so are you saying if someone in say Chinais using my web app the date they see as current may or may not be correct depending on where the server hosting the php is located?

Comment: That fixed it thank you but it still leaves me wondering if my php is hosted in another timezone my date may be off?

Comment: @phpnoobie As long as you specify the timezone explicitly, it should not be a problem (unless the server is misconfigured).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because your local timezone is set to GMT, current GMT is 1/27, and it would have just changed.